# How to add Dao to Room in runtime?

Tags: android, android-room

I am using clean architecture in my app, and due-to module testing I have to keep module logic inside modules. However all examples of constructions of `RoomDatabase` forcing to keep all `DAO`'s inside `RoomDatabase` child class.

Is it possible to split `RoomDatabase` creation and `DAO` attachment place into two different modules(in case if one of them depends from second)?